# How do I select part of an audio track in GarageBand 10.3.2?

Tags: audio, copy-paste, garageband

I'm using GarageBand 10.3.2 on Mojave.  I want to extract part of an MP3 file but I'm having trouble figuring out how to select the part I want.  When I open my track I see the below.

[image: ip]

I want to select a region between 23.25 and 27.  When I hold down the Shift key and click the playhead, and then slide the playhead to the right end where I want the selection to end, I see no visual indicator that I have selected anything.  Indeed when I do Edit -> Copy, open a new project and try and paste something, tehre's nothing there.  How do I select a region?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Sorry. Just noticed you asked for GarageBand and not Logic. Updated answer for GarageBand which has fewer split options.

You have to split the track. Once you've split it, you'll be able to copy the region onto the clipboard and paste into another project.

You can split at the playhead position using Edit > Split Regions at Playhead or use the Cmd-T keyboard shortcut.

[image: Split at playhead location]

Just put the playhead at 23.25, split. Move it to 25.00 and split again. Then you'll have a region you can select and copy onto the clipboard.

Comment: How to select then cut that middle region?